# when we can use 'alike' or 'like'

Tags: grammar, exam-questions

Although they are smaller, chipmunks are ________ most other ground squirrels.
 A. like to 
 B. like as 
 C. like  
 D. alike

the correct answer was 'C'.but I think it must be 'D'.
I thought we can use 'like' between two singular name and 'alike' after plural name or two singular.

```
Noun + is like + Noun
Noun + Noun + are alike
Noun (plural) + are alike
```

why the answer is 'like'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two nouns being compared before (chipmunks) and after (most other ground squirrels) 'like'.

The correct versions with 'alike' would be:

Chipmunks and most other ground squirrels are alike (noun + noun).

Chipmunks are alike (plural noun).